# Problema al borrar un innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro haciendo una práctica sobre una calculadora, y me encuentro con el problema de que al dar reset  bueno borrar, pero al dar de vuelta click los numeros aparecen de nuevo, alguien sabe la razón por la que pasa eso?

```
const  getValueButton = () => { 
    let data = '';
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    for (let i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
      items[i].addEventListener('click', e=> {
        data  += items[i].value
        setValueInScreen(data)
      })
    }
    
  }
  
  const setValueInScreen = (data) => {
    let screen = document.getElementsByClassName('screen-value')[0];
    screen.innerHTML = data
  }

  const clearValueInScreen = () => {
    let clear = document.getElementById('reset');
    clear.addEventListener('click', e=> {
      let screen = document.getElementsByClassName('screen-value')[0];
      screen += screen.innerHTML = ''
    })
  }
```

Comment: Con `screen +=` estás agregando a lo que ya existe a `screen`. Probaste con `screen.innerHTML = ' '` ?

Answer (score 0):

En la primera función, "data" conserva el valor de la cadena.
Aunque la limpies del innerHTML sigue en data y cuando vuelves a presionar un boton concatena las variables anteriores que ahí quedaron guardadas.
Deberías cambiar el scope de "data" y limpiarlo en ClearValueInScreen

Comment: Efectivamente esa era la solución, limpie data  en ClearValueInScreen con toda la logica mundo.

Comment: @julianontiveros No olvides aceptar la respuesta si te fue util para resolver el problema.

Comment: Una disculpa, es que creo que soy novato y no me deja hasta llegar a cierto nivel